# 'DataFrame' object is not callable PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I have a code that should write information to excel using selenium. I have 1 list with some information. I need to write all this to excel, and i have solution. But, when i tried to use it i got **'DataFrame' object is not callable**. How can i solve it?
All this code into iteration:

```
for schools in List: #in the List i have data from excel file with Name of schools 
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    data({
        "School Name":School_list_result[0::17],
        "Principal":School_list_result[1::17],
        "Principal's E-mail":School_list_result[2::17],
        "Type":School_list_result[8::17],
        "Grade Span": School_list_result[3::17],
        "Address":School_list_result[4::17],
        "Phone":School_list_result[14::17],
        "Website":School_list_result[13::17],
        "Associations/Communities":School_list_result[5::17],
        "GreatSchools Summary Rating":School_list_result[6::17],
        "U.S.News Rankings":School_list_result[12::17],
        "Total # Students":School_list_result[15::17],
        "Full-Time Teachers":School_list_result[16::17],
        "Student/Teacher Ratio":School_list_result[17::17],
        "Charter":School_list_result[9::17],
        "Enrollment by Race/Ethnicity": School_list_result[7::17],
        "Enrollment by Gender":School_list_result[10::17],
        "Enrollment by Grade":School_list_result[11::17],
        })
    data.to_excel("D:\Schools.xlsx")
```

In ***School_list_result*** i have this data:

```
'Cape Elizabeth High School',
 'Mr. Jeffrey Shedd',
 'No data.',
 '9-12',
 '345 Ocean House Road, Cape Elizabeth, ME 04107',
 'Cape Elizabeth Public Schools',
 '8/10',
 'White\n91%\nAsian\n3%\nTwo or more races\n3%\nHispanic\n3%\nBlack\n1%',
 'Regular school',
 'No',
 '  Male Female\n Students  281 252',
 '  9 10 11 12\n Students  139 135 117 142',
 '#5,667 in National Rankings',
 'https://cehs.cape.k12.me.us/',
 'Tel: (207)799-3309',
 '516 students',
 '47 teachers',
 '11:1',
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the syntax about how to create a dataframe
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html
So your code should be modified as:

```
for schools in List: #in the List i have data from excel file with Name of schools 
    data = pd.DataFrame(data={
                        "School Name": School_list_result[0::17],
                        "Principal": School_list_result[1::17],
                        "Principal's E-mail": School_list_result[2::17],
                        "Type": School_list_result[8::17],
                        "Grade Span": School_list_result[3::17],
                        "Address": School_list_result[4::17],
                        "Phone": School_list_result[14::17],
                        "Website": School_list_result[13::17],
                        "Associations/Communities": School_list_result[5::17],
                        "GreatSchools Summary Rating": School_list_result[6::17],
                        "U.S.News Rankings": School_list_result[12::17],
                        "Total # Students": School_list_result[15::17],
                        "Full-Time Teachers": School_list_result[16::17],
                        "Student/Teacher Ratio": School_list_result[17::17],
                        "Charter": School_list_result[9::17],
                        "Enrollment by Race/Ethnicity": School_list_result[7::17],
                        "Enrollment by Gender": School_list_result[10::17],
                        "Enrollment by Grade": School_list_result[11::17],
                        })
```

Comment: Before running the code, please make sure that the columns you want to add in the dataframe are of equal length

Comment: Is it possible to somehow lead to the same length?

Comment: I can not quite follow your comment. As i could see now, different columns have different length. e.g. 0::17, 8::17. Perhaps creating a dictionary would help in your case

Comment: you are right, because now i have error "arrays must all be same length"

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add in an existing xlsx file?

First, create the dictionary and then call the DataFrame method, like this:

```
r = {"column1":["data"], "column2":["data"]}
data = pd.DataFrame(r)
```

Comment: after this i won't get "arrays must all be same length" ?

Comment: I did it but it adding 1 school in excel file